# How to convert an entry field value to integer without getting an error?

Tags: python, tkinter

When I try to convert an entry field value to an integer, I always get an error like: Invalid literal for int. How can I convert the entry field to integer so I can do math with the value?

```
 ratep = int(ratee.get())
```

Comment: Use `try / except`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the variable inside the `int()` or `float()` function depending on the type of input you are expecting:

```
>>> inum = "50"
>>> fnum = "50.0"
>>> int(inum)
50
>>> int(fnum)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#54>", line 1, in <module>
    int(fnum)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '50.0'
>>> float(inum)
50.0
>>> float(fnum)
50.0
```

Comment: I do that. for example:  num1 = int(nume.get() where nume is the entry field but I get an error when doing this.By the way, I'm doing this in tkinter.

Comment: Does the field contain non-digit characters? Can you share the code sniplet for the entry field definition and how you get the field, process the data etc?

Comment: No. the field contains only numbers. And to be honest, I'm having trouble posting code. I don't quite understand how to post code. I press control K and a little box shows on the screen that says 'place code here'. Do I place it right into the place where it says that or right before or after it?

Comment: Are you using Python2 or Python3?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.8

Comment: OK, I'm using Python 3.6.9. I'll add a code sample written with Tkinter to see if that works for you.

Comment: That sample code worked but for some reason, it's not working when I try in my program.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213628/discussion-between-tayken-and-codemonster).

Answer (score 0):

tayken answered my problem. Instead of converting entry field to int, I converted it to float instead since the value had a decimal.